# How to get value from button after it has been clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

I'm struggling with this assignment: Pin an event listener to the buttons.
Create a function that gets called when one of the buttons is clicked. Check this with a console.log. Make sure the click event is passed to this function.
**Make sure you have access to the value of the button clicked in this function. Check this with console.log. The outcome you want to see in the console when you click is: Leopard / Lion / Elephant / Rhino or Buffalo.**

```
fiveButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("big-five-button");
for (var i = 0; i < fiveButtons.length; i++) {
    fiveButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        
        Array.from(fiveButtons).forEach(function (nameButton) {
            console.log(nameButton.innerHTML);
        })
    });
}
```

This is what I wrote so far. When I'm clicking the button now, the outcome is the text from all the buttons. While I want the outcome to only be "Lion" after the button lion has been clicked.

```
<h1>The Big Five</h1>
    <ul class="big-five-list">
       <li class="big-five-list-item">
           <button class="big-five-button">Lion</button>
       </li> etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when creating an addEventListener you can use the event object to target the element clicked, like this:

```
fiveButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
       console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: np @Seline :) if that helped you please mark it as the correct answer, tnx –

Answer (score 0):

You can change the button to include an onclick function like the below:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction('Lion')">Lion</button>
<input type="text" value="" id="getValue">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(value) {
  document.getElementById("getValue").value = value;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The onclick function will then have a value inside the () for the function name. This will pass the value you want across to the function and it can be called whatever you want. The above snippet shows an example of how it can be used

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

```
// Get all the buttons
const fiveButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("big-five-button");

// Iterate through the collection of buttons
// Here is let i = 0 instead of var i = 0, since var has functional scope and let has block scope
// If we used var i = 0 it would not work implicitly because i would exist in the scope of a function,
// and all the event handlers (for each button) would share the same value of i
for (let i = 0; i < fiveButtons.length; i++) {

  // For each button register event handler
  fiveButtons[i].addEventListener("click",  _ => {

    // When button is clicked this part of a code is being called
    // Because of javascript CLOSURE, it remembers the i value
    console.log(fiveButtons[i].innerHTML)

  });
```

}

If this is not understandable please read about closures in javascript.

Comment: Can you add details about how the proposed code addresses the problem? Code-only answers are not very helpful, neither for the asker, nor others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution!

```
fiveButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("big-five-button");
    for (var i = 0; i < fiveButtons.length; i++) {
        fiveButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function (item) {
       console.log(item.target.innerHTML);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you pass to `addEventListener` gives an event argument:

```
fiveButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("big-five-button");
for (var i = 0; i < fiveButtons.length; i++) {
    fiveButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) { // use the first argument
        console.log('element value:', event.target.value); // log the 'value' of the event target;
        // I suspect you want the innerHTML or innerText
        console.log('element innerText:', event.target.innerText);
    });
}
```

You can then get the required information from the DOM node in event.target

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the Array.from inside the for loop. You can just do that:

```
fiveButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("big-five-button");
for (let i = 0; i < fiveButtons.length; i++) {
    fiveButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log(fiveButtons[i].innerText);
    });
}
```